# Gap between SwipeRefreshLayout and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, swiperefreshlayout, anko

How to eliminate empty space between those two ?
RecyclerView begins now near the half of the screen and there's blank space from its first element to the toolbar. (Only if I add enough items recyclerview begins on top).

I'm using Kotlin and AnkoLayouts.

```
override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<ConnectBleActivity>): View = with(ui) {
        return relativeLayout {
            lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent)

            addItemButton = floatingActionButton {
                imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_input_add
            }.lparams {
                margin = dip(10)
                alignParentBottom()
                alignParentEnd()
                alignParentRight()
                gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
            }

            swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout {
                rv = recyclerView {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
                    adapter = listAdapter
                    lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
                }
            }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by putting another layout inside SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
 swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout {
                linearLayout {
                    rv = recyclerView {
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true)
                        adapter = listAdapter
                        lparams(width = matchParent, height = wrapContent)
                    }
                }
            }
```